# Shorting pins for several seconds

Tags: short-circuit, pins, 5v

how could I short two pins for 3-5 seconds when  receiving external 5 volts?

Comment: Could you clarify? Depending on what it is you want to do, "shorting two pins" might involve very different things.

Comment: These pins were connected by button that turns on device when you hold it for several seconds. Now I want to turn on this device when external 5v are supplied.

Comment: what does "when receiving" mean? What's the temporal shape of your control signal - is it "should be shorted for how long as the external voltage is 5V", or is it "should be on for X seconds after seeing a 5V pulse", or something else? What's there when there's no 5V?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/228450)

Answer (score 1):

That's called a 5V relay. 5V to the coil, shorts the switched side together.

Comment: You technically could use a relay, however in most cases using another method is far superior.

Comment: @Atsch relays are clunky, power hungry, limited life, and slow... but most other methods require having more knowledge of the circuit to be switched.  For low voltage, low current systems apparently originally intended to use a mechanical switch, the electromagnet actuated mechanical switch that is a relay may be the closest thing to a universal choice when the details are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transistor.

When applying voltage to the Base, current can flow from the Emitter to the Collector.

If the pins you need to short are of different voltage to the 5v, than you can use an optocoupler.

Comment: A transistor *may* be possible, but knowing which one to pick and how to apply it requires determining details of the circuit which have not been stated in the question.